# MySQL linking two tables with another table and running filtered queries

Tags: mysql

Sorry if this has already been posted, I've had a look but don't really know what to search for!

**Problem**

I'm currently setting up a system to 'tag' a student society with various tags. The idea is that we can create and apply any tags we want, then using an API use the tags to authorise different societies for different processes (i.e. check if they have a certain tag applied).

We're also using these tags to create groups of students. I want a user to be able to set up tag filters (for example, they should be able to say 'I want to make a group of all Academic societies who are in the Science faculty', where these groups would be tagged with both the 'Academic' tag and the 'Science' tag).

The design for our tables is outlined below:

```
Societies Table:
+------------+-------------------+
| Society ID |   Society Name    |
+------------+-------------------+
|          1 | Physics Society   |
|          2 | Chemistry Society |
+------------+-------------------+

Tags Table (Where the tags are defined):
+--------+--------------+
| Tag ID |   Tag Name   |
+--------+--------------+
|      1 | Academic     |
|      2 | Science      |
|      3 | Volunteering |
+--------+--------------+

Linking Table:
+---------+--------+----------+
| Link ID | Tag ID | Group ID |
+---------+--------+----------+
|       1 |      1 |        1 |
|       2 |      2 |        1 |
|       3 |      1 |        2 |
|       4 |      2 |        2 |
|       5 |      3 |        2 |
+---------+--------+----------+
```

In this case, the Physics society has been tagged with the Academic and Science tags.

**Attempt at a Solution**

I now need a way to search for specific societies. To ensure any groups can be made, I think we need to include the operators AND, OR and NOT as well as brackets, then construct an SQL query from this? Please correct me if there's a better way to do it!

The user will enter filters in a format like below (this doesn't have to be the case but I couldn't think of any other ways!):

```
({1,3} OR {6}) NOT {5}
```

Using PHP, I then convert this to an SQL query:

```
WHERE (tag_id IN (1,3) OR tag_id IN (6)) AND tag_id NOT IN (5)
```

giving a complete query

```
SELECT tag_links.society_id FROM tag_links WHERE (tag_id IN (1,3) OR tag_id IN (6)) AND tag_id NOT IN (5)
```

This unfortunately doesn't quite work - the results return the same society ID multiple times. I think this is because, as there are multiple rows per society, the query won't exclude any groups tagged with the tag_id 5. It'll just not return the row linking the society and the tag_id 5.

Is there a better way to do this? I haven't had a huge amount of experience with SQL queries beyond the basics, so may be missing something obvious...

Thanks a lot for any help!

Toby

Comment: Why you don't use foreign key ?

Comment: I have been using foreign keys, does that help to create the AND OR NOT filters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a way to find societies having a certain set of tags.  If so, then here is a general query which should work:

```
SELECT
    s.ID, s.Name
FROM Societies s
INNER JOIN Linking lnk
    ON s.ID = lnk.Soc_ID
INNER JOIN Tags t
    ON lnk.Tag_ID = t.ID
WHERE
    t.Name IN ('Academic', 'Science')
GROUP BY
    S.ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.ID) = 2;
```

The above query would find all societies having both tags 'Academic' and 'Science'.  Based on your sample data, this would find the physics society only.

To address your comment below, if you wanted to find societies having two tags, and also *not* having one or more tags, then the query gets a bit uglier, because we need conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    s.ID, s.Name
FROM Societies s
INNER JOIN Linking lnk
    ON s.ID = lnk.Soc_ID
INNER JOIN Tags t
    ON lnk.Tag_ID = t.ID
GROUP BY
    S.ID
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.Name = 'Academic'     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.Name = 'Science'      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.Name = 'Volunteering' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks! This is so much better than my current select query for finding societies with certain tags. How would you go about using a NOT condition in here? For example, finding societies who are Academic and in Science, but not in the Volunteering tag (i.e. it should return just Physics as Chemistry is tagged as volunteering)? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @TobyTwigger I updated with another general query which might fit your needs.